# Placement new crashing when used with virtual inheritance hierarchy in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, virtual-inheritance, placement-new

I am using virtual inheritance with a selection of classes in c++. It is currently crashing on destruction. It seems to compile fine in the online compilers, however when I run in Visual Studio, it crashes.

I have a pure virtual base class, which is being inherited virtually by its implementation. I then have a third class that is inheriting from the implementation regularly. I am using an internal system for creating and releasing memory. Under the hood it is using a placement new with a aligned malloc. It is then using free to free the memory. I have created this minimum example. It is not exactly what I am doing but I seem to get a similar problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    class Animal {
      public:
        Animal() { }
        virtual ~Animal() { }
        virtual void eat() { }

    };

    class Mammal : public virtual Animal {
      public:
        virtual void breathe() { }

    };

    class WingedAnimal : public virtual Animal {
      public:
        virtual void flap() { }
    };

    // A bat is a winged mammal
    class Bat : public Mammal, public WingedAnimal {

    };

   Animal* bat = new(malloc(sizeof(Bat))) Bat;
   bat->~Animal();
   free(bat);
   printf("Done!");
}
```

Like I said, this example will print "Done" in the online compiler. However in Visual Studio 2015 it seems to crash on free of the bat object. I am fairly new to virtual inheritance and placement new. Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: @Barry http://cpp.sh/2vd4t provides exactly that... paste in visual studio and you have the problem. Here is a online one you can use: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/. As I see this response a lot on almost all my questions. Perhaps you could point out what I am missing so I can improve in the future?

Comment: Posting links to code is discouraged. Post code in the question itself.

Comment: @jeff He's using the placement new syntax, so malloc just allocates the raw memory; new initializes it as a C++ object. Then he's explicitly calling the destructor and calling free. This is legal. And derived classes always have a virtual destructor when they inherit from a class that has one.

Comment: Not sure `sizeof (Bat)` is guaranteed to be enough. (alignment, and potentially compiler dependant offset). (and so not sure that address of   `malloc` == `bat`).

Comment: Among other things you should pull the classes out of the main() function. Use the new / delete combination: `Animal* bat = new Bat();  delete(bat);`

Comment: @RawN Yes I am aware of that, this is just an example. I am forced to use that system for various reasons. As I said I am using a internal memory manager and that is the system they are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`malloc` returns some fresh memory address, `operator new` places a `Bat` at that address, and conversion to `Animal*` *adjusts* the address. Now the `bat` variable points somewhere inside the `malloc` block. `free`ing it is impossible.

```
Bat* bat0 = new(malloc(sizeof(Bat))) Bat;
Animal* bat = bat0;
std::cout << bat0 << " " << bat << "\n";
```

`gcc` prints two identical addresses, while `VC++` prints two different ones. Either behaviour is perfectly normal and allowed by the standard, even when no multiple inheritance is involved. Most compilers don't actually adjust the address with single inheritance, but there are some exceptions.

To be on the safe side, don't rely on the two addresses being the same.

It is possible to recover the original address by dynamic casting to `void*`:

```
  free(dynamic_cast<void*>(bat));
```

should be OK. Of course a virtual function is required for the dynamic cast to work, as usual.

Update: `dynamic_cast<void*>` recovers the initial pointer, *but `free` still crashes with VC++*. I have no idea why.

The right method to integrate a third party memory manager in your C++ program is to overload `operator new` and `operator delete`

```
void* ::operator new(size_t sz) { return my_managed_malloc(sz); }
void ::operator delete (void* ptr) { return my_managed_free(ptr); }
```

Place these in any one C++ file in your program (if you have DLLs, then in all DLLs) and use C++ normally, without ill-defined pointer tricks.

For more info, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new .

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense. I am inheriting a code base that uses factory functions a CreateAnimal() and a DestroyAnimal(). Is there anyway to make the existing system work? The animal in my case is a pure virtual class and each implementation is entirely hidden from the user so I cannot have a CreateBat() function. Would I need to internally hold a reference to the proper malloc pointer? Am I correct in assuming a cast to the correct type would not work either as I still have the wrong address?

Comment: Why does calling delete not make the value adjust back? Just as if I had used a normal new call?

Comment: There is no delete. There is a destructor call but it destroys the object, it cannot and should not touch pointers that point to it.

Comment: I more meant if I changed the free to a delete why can it not make the adjustment again. The dynamic cast does not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Why  not just use normal new/delete? Delete actually adjusts the pointer back, but you cannot combine malloc and delete.

Comment: Because I am using a internal memory manager that allocates memory for you. The only allocation they provide is a malloc no new. If I used a new it would not go through our internal tool which tracks many things.

Comment: Overload operators `new` and `delete` to use your internal tool instead of the default implementation. Then you don't have to do any of these pointer tricks.

Comment: Good idea! Thanks.