# Unable to call virtual functions on class created with malloc/placement new

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, vtable, placement-new

I trying to write new/delete functions for my custom allocator but objects initialized with placement new are throwing a "access violation executing location" whenever a virtual function is called.

When I try allocating two objects of the same class, one with new and one with placement new, their vptrs point to the same functions but only the object created with new is able to execute the function.

```
//Definition not shown
class Component
{
public:
    Component() {}
    virtual void Update() {}
    virtual void Init() {}


};

//Definition not shown
class MeshComponent :
    public Component
{
public:
    virtual void Update() override;
    virtual void Init() override;
};


#define fnew(T,...) new (malloc(sizeof(T))) T (__VA_ARGS__);

MeshComponent* newComponent = fnew(MeshComponent);
MeshComponent* newComponent2 = new MeshComponent();

newComponent2->Update(); //Runs like expected
newComponent->Update();  //Access violation executing location
```

Any idea why this is?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works as expected with gcc 8. What compiler / os?

Comment: Post some compilable code.

Comment: Huh, I'm on windows. Msvc in visual studio.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246633/placement-new-crashing-when-used-with-virtual-inheritance-hierarchy-in-visual-c

Comment: Works for me on vs2017. But please add a MVCE.

Answer (score 0):

Well I restarted Visual Studio and its working now...
Thanks for the insight, all.